# select n rows prior to row that match select condition

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a big table of process data from a production line that consists of many steps a product goes through during its creation in a Hadoop datalake.  At certain points I am interested in finding out what happened N steps before a certain process took place.

I can write a select query which returns the rows corresponding to the process I can identify but how (and should I) can I return N rows prior to the one which meets my actual select query?

I want to know if it is possible to do such a thing in SQL/pyspark and if I should do it or if something like this should be done in python after selecting a much bigger set of data which contains the information I want and using python to filter out just the bits I need.

Example table structure:

```
|Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3| Col 4  |
|A     | 1     | One  | Date 1 |
|C     | 1     | Two  | Date 2 |
|B     | 1     | One  | Date 1 |
|C     | 2     | Two  | Date 2 |
|C     | 1     | Three| Date 3 |
|D     | 2     | Four | Date 1 |
|E     | 1     | Five | Date 5 |

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE COL 1 = "C" and COL 3 = "Three"
ORDER BY COL 4, Col 2
```

What would be returned

```
|Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3| Col 4  |
|C     | 1     | Three| Date 3 |
```

What I would like to be returned

```
|Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3| Col 4  |
|C     | 1     | One  | Date 2 |
|C     | 2     | Two  | Date 2 |
|C     | 1     | Three| Date 3 |
```

above N=2, but N should be variable.  If an implementation is possible in SQL I am really interested in if this is something that should be done in SQL or if it is better to do it in code after.  I can see arguments for both sides but need some outside opinions.

Edit: Both of the suggested approaches seemed to rely on the structure I provided previously where Col 2 was an incrementaly increasing value.  This was misleading as I used Col 2 and the numbers as dummy values.  I have now updated the table with two columns which show actually how the table is ordered correctly.  First by a column which contains a datetime stamp and second by a column which contains an integer number.

The table is a table in a Hadoop datalake so suggested solutions should provide SQL which can execute in that environment.

Edit 2: It has also become apparent the rows themselves may not necessarily be consecutive so I don't want the last N rows but rather the last N rows that also meet a certain predicate.  In the example above the predicate would be where Col2 = "C".

Comment: you mean COL 3 = "Three" I believe, as your Col2 is numeric.

Comment: you are 100% correct

Comment: Hi, so regarding pyspark solution- yes, it would definitely be better performing, but it would also require more work. Do you have anything on your end prepared for it? Like spark context definition, or connection to the SQL database at least? If it's for you to start from scratch with pyspark, it's not worth it- go with SQL, unless as an learning exercise.

Comment: pyspark and connection everything is setup.  Its sort of a productive task coupled with a learning exercise.  SQL on Apache spark or pyspark with spark context are fine and working with the extracted data is also fine, its more about how to extract the data optimally and where my efforts are best spent educating myself in this area.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` function like below:

```
Declare @n int = 3

SELECT *
FROM (
   select Col1,Col2,Col3,
          Row_Number() over (ORDER BY Col2 ASC) as RowOrder
   from table1
) x
where x.RowOrder <= @n
```

Comment: If my data normally has to be ordered by two columns that don't have a simplified order like Col 2 here, would this still work?  And should something like this be done in SQL or is it better to do it with something like python?

Comment: I'd do it in SQL, it'd be providing better performance and would be easier to debug via SQL Profiler. Such an approach: Row_number() over (ORDER BY COL2,COL3 asc)) might also work, or you may need to have two different roworder columns then order your main query based on your roworder columns as well (using order by). Need to see the data speaking more certain.

Comment: I have to add in a where clause into the inner select because the table is too big to select all of it, when I do this i only get the rows returned which exactly meet the the condition of the initial select I specified and not the preceeding N rows as well.  Is this because I put in a where clause?

Comment: @Aesir I think you shouldn't have and COL 3 = "Three" in the where clause.

Comment: "I'd do it in SQL, it'd be providing better performance" this is very bold statement. I dare say - mostly untrue, if you put your pyspark code right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a running count:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN COL1 = 'D' AND COL2 = 'Three THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  OVER (ORDER BY col2 ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) as cnt_special
      FROM Table1 t1
WHERE cnt_special > 0;
```

Or, you can use window functions to identify the `col2` value.  This works if you want the offset to be logical (i.e. based on the *values* in `col2`) rather than physical (i.e. the number of rows):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN COL1 = 'D' AND COL2 = 'Three THEN col2 END)  OVER (ORDER BY col2) as special_col2
      FROM Table1 t1
WHERE col2 <= special_col2 and col2 >= special_col2 - 2
```

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it to work.  My order by involves two columns which I updated my question to show.  Sorry if that was confusing.  Syntactically I also get an error with rows_between: mismatched input 'rows_between' expecting {')', ',', 'RANGE', 'ROWS'}(line 2, pos 129).  Would this be because I am running a SQL query on a table in a Hadoop datalake?

Comment: @Aesir . . . There is no underscore in `rows between`.  That was a typo.